# How to select a PDF file using startActivityForResult intent and return result in a second class

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to android programming, I want to create a pdf reader that calls the inbuilt file manager to select pdf file and then display the pdf file in a second class. Here is my code so far still having issues, i think second activity is unable to get the selected pdf file and I am unable to fix this error

```
     MainActivity

     package com.example.user.projectapp;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.app.ListActivity;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.ListView;

     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.net.URI;
     import java.net.URISyntaxException;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Collections;
     import java.util.List;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public static String path;
     private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
     File tempFile;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getFile();
     }

      public void getFile() {

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      intent.setType("application/pdf");
      path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
      intent.putExtra("path",path);
      startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
      }

      Second Activity


      package com.example.user.projectapp;

      import android.annotation.TargetApi; 
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.graphics.Bitmap;
      import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
      import android.os.Build;
      import android.os.Environment;
      import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.ImageView;

      import java.io.File;


      public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

      int pagecount = -1;
      Button buttonnext, buttonprevious;
      ImageView imageView;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

      buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      buttonprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);


      buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pagecount++;

            render();

        }
       });
     buttonprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pagecount--;

            render();
        }
       });

       }

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
       public void render() {

       try {
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("path");
        File file = new File(data);

        PdfRenderer renderer = new              PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

        if (pagecount < 0) {
            pagecount = 0;
        } else if (pagecount > renderer.getPageCount()) {
            pagecount = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }
        renderer.openPage(pagecount).render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.invalidate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
    }
```

And the Logcat gives

```
    03-28 17:19:33.387 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
    03-28 17:19:33.400 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
    03-28 17:19:33.400 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at com.example.user.projectapp.Main2Activity.render(Main2Activity.java:69)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at com.example.user.projectapp.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:42)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    03-28 17:19:33.401 2492-2492/com.example.user.projectapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Code Modified to be based on one activity only......
yet onActivityResult does not return a result, I

```
File myFile;
public static String result;
public String path;
private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 12;
int pagecount = -1;
Button buttonnext, buttonprevious;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFile();

    buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);


    buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pagecount++;

            render();

        }
    });
    buttonprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pagecount--;

            render();
        }
    });

}
public void getFile() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    //intent.setType("image/");
    // path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
     //intent.putExtra("path",path);
    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 12);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==12){
        if (data != null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"file selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          // result=data.getStringExtra("data");
            Uri uri=data.getData();
          //  String uriString = uri.toString();
             myFile = new File(uri.toString());
            path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
           // result=data.toString();
           // URI uri=data.getParcelableExtra(path);
           // path=fileUri.toString();
            this.render();
        }

    }

}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void render() {

    try {
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //String path = intent.getStringExtra("path");

        // Uri uri = Uri.parse(uri_Str);
         File file = new File(path);
        //File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);


        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

        if (pagecount < 0) {
            pagecount = 0;
        } else if (pagecount > renderer.getPageCount()) {
            pagecount = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }

        // Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
        // Rect rect=new Rect(0,0,width,height);
        renderer.openPage(pagecount).render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        //imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.invalidate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And the logcat error...

```
    03-29 11:32:47.276 21674-21674/com.example.user.newtry W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
    03-29 11:32:47.283 21674-21674/com.example.user.newtry W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
    03-29 11:32:47.283 21674-21674/com.example.user.newtry W/System.err:     at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
    03-29 11:32:47.283 21674-21674/com.example.user.newtry W/System.err:     at      android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
```

Comment: So you have issues. Interesting.

Comment: Can you help with a solution?

Comment: Solution for what? There is no problem description. There are no questions. You still dont understand you need to write a decent post first?

Comment: I have edited the post, thank you.

Comment: After you have done that you are expected to tell us which big problem is reported in your log.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code, it will not give you error:

MainActivity

```
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.net.URI;
        import java.net.URISyntaxException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String path;
    private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    File tempFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getFile();
    }

    public void getFile() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //intent.setType("application/pdf");

       // path = intent.getStringExtra("path");
      //  intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
      //  intent.putExtra("path", path);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("uri",uriString + " " + path);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putParcelable("path", uri);
           // intent.putExtra();
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int pagecount = -1;
    Button buttonnext, buttonprevious;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        buttonnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);


        buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pagecount++;

                render();

            }
        });
        buttonprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pagecount--;

                render();
            }
        });

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void render() {

        try {
            int width = imageView.getWidth();
            int height = imageView.getHeight();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Uri data = extras.getParcelable("path");
            Log.d("Soanam","path" + data);
            File file = new File(data.toString());

            PdfRenderer renderer = new              PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

            if (pagecount < 0) {
                pagecount = 0;
            } else if (pagecount > renderer.getPageCount()) {
                pagecount = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
            }
            renderer.openPage(pagecount).render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Modify it according to your requirement

Comment: Running it exactly as pasted above i still got this:   03-29 10:18:22.602 10094-10094/com.example.user.mpdfreader W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-29 10:18:22.603 10094-10094/com.example.user.mpdfreader W/System.err:     at com.example.user.mpdfreader.Main2Activity.render(Main2Activity.java:65)

Comment: It seems like the selected file is not received at onActivityResult

Comment: Did you get any file selection UI?

Comment: I did, that worked properly and i selected a pdf file, which launched the second activity. But the file selected cannot be read.

Comment: I did not get any error in my case... please check whether proper path is being returned or not

Comment: onActivityResult gets and return the proper path.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.. because your path is null.. this is the reason you are getting null pointer exception

Comment: How do i fix this please?

Comment: Please paste full code of MainActivity.java.. Its missing